# Are finite type analytic sheaves coherent?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let $X$ be an open subset of $\mathbb C^n$, and let $\mathcal O_X$ be the structure sheaf of germs of holomorphic functions. Suppose that $\mathcal F$ is a finitely generated $\mathcal O_X$-modules, i.e., there is an exact sequence $\mathcal O_X^m\rightarrow\mathcal F\rightarrow 0$ (where $m\in\mathbb N$). Is it true that $\mathcal F$ is coherent? What about the algebraic case?

Comment: I think Oka's theorem will say that $\mathcal{O}_X$ is coherent and then the rest will easily follow.

Comment: Hi Mohan, thanks for the reply! I would like to know how to use the coherence of structure sheaf to prove this. Btw is my question well known to be true?

Comment: What definition of coherence are you using?

Comment: well, I want to check that the sheaf of relations is finitely generately.

Comment: You did not tell me your definition of coherence.

Comment: By coherence I mean F is finitely generated, and for any O_X module homomorphism O_X^p ---> F (where p=1,2,...) its kernal sheaf is also finitely generated. (Isn't this the only definition of coherent sheaf in the analytic setting?)

Comment: By your (standard) definition coherence of $O_X$ says $O_X^n$ is coherent for any  (finite) $n$ and thus any subsheaf of $O_X^n$ is finitely generated.

Comment: This might be stupid, but why does the coherence of $\mathcal O^n_X$ imply that any of its subsheaf is finitely generated?

Comment: I don't think so. Let $n>2$ and let $K\subset \mathbb C^n=X$ be a closed, nowhere dense, non-analytic subset, like $S^1\times 0$. Moreover, let $I\subset \mathcal O_X$ be the ideal of germs vanishing along $K$. Then I think the support of $\mathcal F=\mathcal O_{X}/I$ should be $K$, but if $\mathcal F$ were coherent, the support would be analytic. In other words, $I$ is not locally finitely generated.

Comment: @Ben Nice example! I think what you said is true even in the simpliest case $n=1$. One can then show by hand that $I$ is not finitely generated near $K=S^1$.

Comment: I wasn't sure about this since my analysis feels a bit rusty, but you're probably right. What about $n=1$ and a countable set with an accumulation point?

Comment: @Ben I think in this case you can just define functions in $J(U)$ to be $0$ when $U$ intersects $K$. Then $J$ is an ideal of $\mathcal O_X$ which is not finitely generated (near $K$). This is a quiet general construction and does not depend how $K$ looks like. One only needs to assume that $K$ is not dense in $X\subset \mathbb C$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summing up the comments: Let $X$ be any complex space, e. g., an open subset of $\mathbb C^n$ with its sheaf of germs of holomorphic functions. The support of a coherent sheaf on $X$ is an analytic subset. Thus, given $A\subset X$ closed but not analytic, it suffices to construct a finitely generated sheaf supported exactly on $A$.

Let $i\colon A\to X$ be the inclusion map; I claim that $i_*i^{-1}\mathcal O_X$ is such a sheaf. Consider the natural morphism $\mathcal O_X\to i_*i^{-1}\mathcal O_X$. Since $A$ is closed in $X$, $(i_*i^{-1}\mathcal O_X)_x = \mathcal O_{X,x}$ whenever $x\in A$ and otherwise $(i_*i^{-1}\mathcal O_X)_x = 0$. Therefore, $\mathcal O_X\to i_*i^{-1}\mathcal O_X$ is surjective, hence, $i^{-1}\mathcal O_X$ is finitely generated and indeed $A = \mathrm{supp}(i_*i^{-1}\mathcal O_X)$.

Alternatively, as the OP has proposed, we may simply define the ideal $I\subset\mathcal O_X$ to be $I(U) = \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ if $U\cap A = \emptyset$ and $I(U) = 0$ otherwise. It is then easy to see that this is not finitely generated near $A$; hence, the quotient $\mathcal O_X/I$ is not coherent. (This works even is $A$ is analytic.)

In the "algebraic case", the analogous construction produces non-quasi-coherent ideals, hence, non-quasi-coherent finitely generated sheaves.